# Overiding an inline style with !important from a .css file

Tags: html, css

I'm aware technically you can't do this as inline always takes president.
Inline element with styles:

```
element.style {
    width: 185px !important;
}
```

and then inside a style.css file:

```
.something ul li {
     width: 179px !important;
}
```

I thought maybe if i just got more specific i could override it, even though i know this isn't technically possible.

Also i don't want to use JS to override it.

Comment: Have you read http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity?

Comment: i have, just told me what i already thought :/ but its not working so i thought to ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume instead of president you mean "precedence".

I was always aware that you could override inline styles from the css file using exactly the method that you outlined. For instance, this url explains exactly that procedure: http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

Comment: spell check :p, but indeed i thought it worked this way, but its not working, made me question myself.

Comment: Any particular browser combination you are working with? A brief perusal of the webz tells me that it doesn't work for different versions of browsers. However, it works for Chrome 18.0x - which is the only browser I have on now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overexaggerate using `!important`. You see what the consequences are. You usually get along very well structuring your selectors in a reasonable way. `!important` should only be used in exceptional cases. Then you won't have issues with selectors which suddenly are more specific than inline styles.

Comment: yup, i have a plugin which is js'ing in the styles and uses important. So of course i have to use it as well.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like an exceptional case. ;-) Nevertheless I'd rather look for a way to produce well structured style assignments. What kind of plugin is that, if I may ask?

Comment: plugin wasn't the right terminology, my apologies. Its javascript which lets me use Single sign up. So more of an JS applet. It adds lots of markup.